# Wait for parallel remote process to finish bash ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, parallel-processing, background-process

I am trying to run a script on several linux machines in the background. My bash script looks like this:

```
for i in {1..1000}; do  
  for j in {1..20}; do      
    ssh -n -f remotehost$j "sh -c 'cd /blah/; nohup ./script.sh $i > /dev/null 2>&1 &'"
    NPROC=$(($NPROC+1))
    if [ "$NPROC" -ge 40 ]; then
        echo "Waiting for work to finish"
        wait
        NPROC=0
    fi        
  done    
done
```

This is my attempt to limit the load on the servers and only have a net of 40 processes run over 20 hosts at any given time. This does not work though and all processes start at the same time. Could you please guide me on how to either wait for remote background process to finish or to prevent more than n processes from starting up on a given remote host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU Parallel you can do this to run 40 jobs on every of the 20 machines:

```
parallel -j20 seq 1000 \| parallel -j40 -I I ssh server{} \''"cd /blah/; ./script.sh I"'\' ::: {1..20}
```

The 10 seconds installation will try do to a full installation; if
that fails, a personal installation; if that fails, a minimal
installation:

```
wget -O - pi.dk/3 | bash
```

or:

```
curl pi.dk/3/ | bash
```

Watch the intro video for a quick introduction:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial (man parallel_tutorial). You command line
with love you for it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use tools that were designed specifically for this purpose. I use [pssh](http://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/) (aka parallel ssh), and it works pretty well.

Also, it is widely available in common Linux repositories, for example in Ubuntu you can install it using `sudo apt-get install pssh`.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout GNU Parallel as well: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/.

Answer (score 0):

Run the remote processes in the foreground, and put `ssh` in the background:

```
ssh -n -f remotehost$j "sh -c 'cd /blah/; ./script.sh $i > /dev/null 2>&1 '" &
```

Comment: Looked very promising but wait does not work with this and all processes start up together. Checked my input to ensure that it is correct but can't spot why this doesn't work.

Comment: Make sure the remote command doesn't redirect stdin. One of the standard file descriptors has to stay connected to the SSH connection, so that ssh will wait for the remote command to complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [xargs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) to limit the number of processes:

```
maxPerServer=2
for j in {1..20}; do
    echo -n {1..1000} | xargs -P "$maxPerServer" -d ' ' ssh -n -f remotehost$j "sh -c 'cd /blah/; ./script.sh {} > /dev/null 2>&1 '" &
done
```

This code will run max 2 processes per server.

Comment: Tried this approach too. Script executes fine but nothing happens. i.e no remote processes are started.

Comment: Are you sure? Try placing ``wait`` in the end of the script.

Answer (score 0):

A parallel SSH client (pdsh, cssh, pssh, etc) would be the way to go.